how to fix python problem
he following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.191~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.191~) but it is not installable or
                        base-files (< 12.3)
               Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

how to fix python problem

This question is similar to: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

deb packages are built for specific releases, and as we don't know yours (you've not told us), we can only provide generic advice.  Providing the actual command & full messages are also useful; ie. I'd apt policy the package involved in your command & contrast it with your actual release (or if this is side effect of prior command, the package(s) that caused the problem & your release)

I queried grub-efi-amd64-signed and see it available for seven releases, and for some releases that meet your requirements (but I don't know your release) so I suggest you work out what you're running, and if you're on a release where the package is available; return to sudo apt update for issues (ie. are there missing errors there? or missing lines etc).

This question is similar to: E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

grub seen in all messages above; I'd say this is not a python problem, possibly just revealed by a python -related action. You need to provide more detail for it to be decipherable.
